# Ubuntu 14.04 Adding #10 Envelope to Samsung M2070

Tags: 14.04, printing, libreoffice, samsung

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, got Samsung M2070 added as my printer. Trying to print #10 envelopes from LibreOffice, when I ctrl+p, the preview shows letter size paper. Clicked properties and saw that #10 envelope is not an option, shows Letter, Legal, A4, Executive, US Folio, JIS B5, ISO B5, A5 and Oficio, all paper sizes, but no envelopes. Does anyone know how to add it?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out how to print a #10 envelope with LibreOffice on Samsung M2070. Open a new document in Libreoffice, go to top of frame, click Insert, scroll down and click Envelope. A window titled Envelope will open, you can add the Addressee and Sender. Once that is done, click Format tab, under Size, click drop down menu of Format and choose #10 Envelope. Finally, click New Document tab at bottom and review your work. If all information is correct, adjust paper tray on printer, place envelope in printer and click the Print Icon.